# Rails Model Data transformation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a total newbie to rails, and want to stop making the same tedious reports in excel and create a marketing analytics dashboard.

I have a User model, with created_at, marketing_source, purchases, and revenue.

What I want to do in sql is

```
select marketing_source, weekofyear(created_at), count(id), sum(revenue) 
from User 
where weekofyear(created_at) between # and #
group by marketing_source, weekofyear(created_at)
```

and then print this as a table to my page.

I'm just not exactly sure where and how to do the transformation. Do I put this via

```
sql.execute
```

in the controller code? Should I create a rake task to make a csv and then use javascript to read the csv and print out the table?

Any direction would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't provide enough info to receive an answer. Please provide as much info as you possibly can, since your question isn't very specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to rails

If you are new to rails check out [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com) and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

In rails you don't have to write sql statements like this.

I am assuming you have done the database migrations and have all the necessary columns in you database

in your users_controller, I think this would do what you want.

```
def index
 @users = User.where
 (["created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", yesterday.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day]).
 group("marketing_source")
end
```

Then in your corresponding view
/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>revenue</th>
    <th>Marketing source</th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h user.name %></td>
    <td><%=h user.revenue %></td>
    <td><%=h user.marketing_source %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance! I think this will put me towards the right direction, especially with the controller help.